# Can terraform providers generate implicit output variables?

Tags: terraform

Is it possible for a custom terraform provider to generate an output variable implicitly, i.e. without the terraform user defining an output variable in their .tf file?

A bit more context -- we have a system that invokes user's terraform scripts, and wants to detect the existence of a resource. Is it possible to determine if a resource is used or not without having to parse the user's terraform? The thought was the provider associated with this resource could some how publish its existence via an output variable, or produce some external side-effect.

Comment: Could you query the state file for the named resource via `terraform state show` https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/show.html ?

Comment: Will need to think about it. Based on what I read, the address of the state includes the resource name, rather than a facility to lookup for resource state by resource type alone.  ... Maybe terraform state list, and doing a prefix search.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this depends a little on what you mean by a resource "existing". Based on your reference to module outputs I think you may intend it to mean that one or more instances of the resource are recorded in the Terraform state. If that's true, you can execute `terraform show -json` to get [a JSON representation of what's currently recorded in the state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/json-format.html#state-representation).

In that JSON output you can iterate over the `resources` array in a module to see all of the resource instances in it. Each one will have an `address` property giving the resource instance address in the usual Terraform syntax, like `aws_instance.example[0]`.

---

If you instead mean whether something exists *in the configuration*, independently of whether it has already been created and recorded in the state, there is not currently any built-in way to get that answer without parsing the Terraform configuration itself.

HashiCorp has a helper library [`terraform-config-inspect`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-config-inspect) which has associated with it a little tool that can produce a JSON representation of the inspect result; using that would at least avoid you having to re-implement HCL decoding, but you may need to keep upgrading to newer verions of that library as the Terraform language evolves in future.

That library is what [the Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/) uses to extract metadata about modules, for example. One key advantage of it, compared to the parsing/decoding that Terraform itself does, is that it attempts to support all versions of the Terraform language since Terraform 0.10 so that the registry can extract metadata for modules regardless of which version of Terraform they are written for. However, it can only help with *backward* compatibility, because that library can't predict what new features may be added to the language later.

Comment: thanks for sharing those links. For the purposes of this Q, the former interpretation applies, and iterating through the state looking for resources + matching prefix should work.